# Apache poi need all formula cell with separator

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using apache poi 3.9.In my workbook certain cells have formula cell. I need a data format for all formula cells.

```
Map<String, XSSFCellStyle> styles = new HashMap<String, XSSFCellStyle>();
XSSFCellStyle style;
XSSFDataFormat format = (XSSFDataFormat) workBook.createDataFormat();

style = (XSSFCellStyle) workBook.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("###,##0.00"));
styles.put("amountStyle", style);
```

I want to know how to add style **amountStyle** in formula cell.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/33311602/6583528](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33311602/6583528) Check this might be helpful to you

Comment: @SM In above example given Cell position is to set format but what I need to set dataformat for all formula cell without given Cell position or any iterator is possible?

Comment: You will need to iterate over every cell and check if its a formula cell and if yes you have to call `cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("amountStyle")):`. There is no way around it